# WordPress Search not returning all post that contain query string

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation which contains many posts. When I search for a keyword such as "epic" it will return posts that contain "epic" in their titles but not if only the content contains "epic". **I need a way for the search to return all posts that contain the search keyword in either their title or content or tag.**

I'm new to Wordpress backend development and every article/documentation I've read on WP search says that the search will search through content as well.

I'm trying to stay away from plugins unless it's absolutely unavoidable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out after messing around with some of the code in `wp-includes/query.php`. Evidently, WordPress does display all post that have the the keyword in the title and content however they display the list of results in order of posts with the keyword in the title first and then the posts that have the keyword in the content second. I need to have this display all the posts in order of their post date.